# Prebuild event Copy command exits with code 1

Tags: visual-studio-2010, pre-build-event

I have the following in a prebuild event:

```
copy /y $(ProjectDir)ThirdPartyAssemblies\ $(TargetDir)
```

Which results in the following error:

> The command "copy /y C:\Users\myusername\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\mysolution\myproject\ThirdPartyAssemblies* C:\Users\myusername\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\mysolution\myproject\bin\Debug\" exited with code 1.

I've tried it in a post build event too and get the same error. Yet when I run the command it results in (the one in the error) in a console window it works fine.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's related to the error you're receiving, but you need to place quotes around your path/file names since there are spaces in them.

copy /y "C:\Users\myusername\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\mysolution\myproject\ThirdPartyAssemblies*" "C:\Users\myusername\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\mysolution\myproject\bin\Debug\"

Comment: That was it, thanks - of course, I put the quotes in when I tested in the console, but it didn't occur to me that VS would need them too.

Answer (score 15):

`copy /y "$(SolutionDir)MyProject\myFile.xxx" "$(TargetDir)"` did not work for me. I pulled my hair out for 45 minutes until I stumbled across [this page](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/240268) and then tried:

```
xcopy /y "$(SolutionDir)MyProject\myFile.xxx" "$(TargetDir)"
```

Answer (score 5):

Also, you can do it by macros. In Post/Pre Build Event Command Line, expand macros.

```
copy  "$(TargetPath)" "$(SolutionDir)MyProject\Bin\Debug\";
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the path you have written inside command prompt, it can not found file or folder.

Answer (score -2):

In my case I changed the solution configuration from release to debug on each project and it solved the problem.